# Problems displaying paragraphs when retrieving text from a database

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I am having problems displaying chucks of text, with paragraphs, from a database.

For example, if I pass in a string such as:

```
local lotsOfText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n\nNunc euismod justo sapien, at sollicitudin lacus. Quisque vestibulum commodo felis id posuere."
```

Then the \n\n creates a paragraph break in the text, which is what I would expect.

However, if I retrieve exactly the same string as above from a database, for example:

```
local lotsOfText = row.Info
```

Then the \n\n are displayed on the screen, rather than paragraph break.

Any help would be gratefully received!

---

Thanks everyone for their ideas and suggestions. Based on what  BMitch said, I tried a different approach and believe this is actually a problem with my database, rather than Lua or the string itself.

If I create a DB table in code and insert the string, I can them retrieve it correctly. I thin k this is due to the data type I was using, or maybe something to do with how I am editing data in Lita.

Comment: Welcome to SO MattK.  You should show your code, including the string the prints ok, the process of inserting that very string into the db, the process of retrieving the string, and the process of printing the string incorrectly.  Don't include all of your code, only what's needed to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same issue when I was writing a short build script in Python.  The problem turned out to be that Python was treating the string result returned from a process call to be binary.  I imagine Lua is doing the same thing.  Although I've never personally encountered this and I couldn't find a direct solution via Google, someone else mentioned the [lpack](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lpack) library for packing & unpacking binary data in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259770/reading-a-binary-file-into-an-array).  Also, the string.dump and loadstring functions *may* point you toward a solution, in case lpack doesn't do what you're looking for, but I think the key thing is finding out an existing way (or writing your own) to interpret the "binary" data as characters.

Answer (score 0):

Escapes are only processed when inside a single quoted or double quoted string literal.

The problem is that your database is storing '\n' instead of actually storing a paragraph break.

If you can't fix the database, you can process it afterwards with a smart gsub:

```
mystring = string.gsub(mystring,[[\(%a)]],{n="\n",r="\r",t="\t"})
```